# Load external file variable and at the same time avoid browser external file caching

Tags: javascript, scope

I need to append timestamp to the javaScript file in  tag url to avoid caching.

This function found here in stackoverflow seems to do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){ 
 var randomh=Math.random();
 var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
 var d = document.createElement("script");
 d.src = "TESTINGX.JS?x="+randomh+"";
 d.type = "text/javascript"; 
 d.async = true;
 d.defer = true;
 e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
```

})();

But the problem is that inside the file testingx.js I've placed the following code:

```
var hello = "Hello World!";
```

And for some reason the variable doesn't get the global scope (or maybe the problem is other).

My html is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML><HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){ 
     var randomh=Math.random();
     var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     var d = document.createElement("script");
     d.src = "TESTINGX.JS?x="+randomh+"";
     d.type = "text/javascript"; 
     d.async = true;
     d.defer = true;
     e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
 })();
</script>

</HEAD><BODY>

<h1>WiFi Mini Web Server</h1>

<script>
document.write(hello); //hello var is contained in the TESTINGX.JS file\n\
</script>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: and if you remove the var keyword?  Leaving `var` off should make the variable inherently global.

Comment: I tried it and didn't work, so now I'm thing the problem may be related with what psr commented below or both problems combined.

Comment: now I tested the code of PSR and removed the word var and still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the external script to block everything else until it loads but still need to load it from a dynamic URL (it sounds like you do), you should be able to `document.write` the script element directly instead of using the DOM methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>

<script>
var randomh = Math.random();
document.write('<script src="TESTINGX.JS?x=' + randomh + '"></' + 'script>');
</script>

</head><body>

<h1>WiFi Mini Web Server</h1>

<script>
document.write(hello); // hello var is contained in the TESTINGX.JS file
</script>

</body></html>
```

http://jsbin.com/ixagud/2/edit

Comment: Yep, it did work on my embedded device too, really simple, I definitely don't know much javaScript

Comment: Thank you very much to you and all others that generously tried to help me

Comment: The code for the embedded device will be here: http://www.libstock.com/projects/view/632/minimalistic-wifi-http-with-microsd-storage

Comment: Just in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You code for cache busting, also happens to ensure that the script is loaded in a "lazy", "non-blocking" manner. Which means the `TESTING.js` is loaded *after* your DOM is loaded. Which also means that the `document.write` script is run before the js file has loaded, and added the required var to the global scope.

There can be several solutions:
1. Remove `defer` and `async` from your loading script

1. Ensure variables from your script are accessed on your page, only after the script is actually loaded
2. Better yet, don't try to handle cache busting through clever javascript (I am assuming the html is question is served using some sort of server technology like a jsp or php script). Use the server technology to add a parameter with a random number or timestamp to the usual script tag in the html
3. Instead of using a script to bust cache, use a normal script tag, with a parameter that is same as the timestamp in millis, as on the day when you make the build, and embed in your microcontroller / server. Treat this like a version number of the js file. So clients can use the file cached in their browser, provided the version number is the latest.

This ant task http://code.google.com/p/ant-web-tasks/wiki/CacheBusting is a good way to implement point no 4. I have had good experience with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also tested it Removing defer and async from my loading script and still doesn't work.

Comment: I can not use a server side code because my web page is embedded into a microcontroller (a small computer chip shaped), so I can only rely on client side coding.

Comment: How can I ensure variables from my script are accessed on my page, only after the script is actually loaded?

Comment: I just tried your page with a basic testingx.js with `var hello = "testing"`, I removed the `async` and `defer` lines, and the page now works.

Comment: Well I don't know what I'm doing wrong but is not working for me

Comment: which browser are you using? Also, for my understanding, your html / js files are embedded, but do clients access the page through a normal browser? or do you have some sort of embedded browser that the user uses?

Comment: First of all before embedding the code I was testing it locally (in my computer without server) and noticed that works for IE but not for firefox or chrome

Comment: I added a point 4 to my answer. That's the best I can do, because I still cannot understand the constraints your application has to be deployed under. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){ 
     var randomh=Math.random();
     var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     var d = document.createElement("script");
     d.src = "TESTINGX.JS?x="+randomh+"";
     d.type = "text/javascript"; 
     d.async = true;
     d.defer = true;
     e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
document.write(hello);
 })();
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you mean var hello = "Hello World!"; and yes I have it like this, I just made a typing error when asking the question.

Comment: here document.write(hello); is calling before loading the file